# From Fixed size array of pointers to dynamic size array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to transition from using a fixed size array of pointers to a dynamic one.
Currently the code looks like:

```
struct myType *fixed_bufs[TEST_SZ];
```

Each element from fixed_bufs is allocated in memory by another module; the pointers to them are just stored in fixed_bufs and eventually freed and another one are added, and so on.

Now, i want to make TEST_SZ dynamic, meaning ( as far as my C knowledge goes ) i will do:

```
struct myType **bufs;
```

along with a preliminary allocation of memory for storing just pointers:

```
bufs = (struct myType **)malloc(TEST_SZ * sizeof(struct myType *));
```

Does this makes sense and is correct/legal ?
My other module is just doing behind the scenes:

```
    struct myType *v1 = malloc(sizeof(struct myType));
    v1->a = 1024+i;
    v1->b = 2048+i;
```

and then it stores the pointer in my pointer array:

```
    bufs[i] = v1;
```

After a certain time, the memory of the elements stored in my list are freed and the my pointer list is repopulated.

**I'm asking this because my app is somehow works, but it crashes in a weird way and i can't debug it.**

I've created a small demo test app below to better describe the situation
**Is a memory allocation step that i'm missing ?**

I just want to store pointers, the actual data is allocated and freed by the other module, as i've already said.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myType {
    int a;
    int b;
};

#define TEST_SZ 2048

void fill_data(struct myType **bufs)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SZ; i++)
    {
        struct myType *v1 = malloc(sizeof(struct myType));
        v1->a = 1024+i;
        v1->b = 2048+i;
        bufs[i] = v1;
    }
}

void empty_data(struct myType **data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SZ; i++)
    {
        free(data[i]);
    } 
}


int main()
{   
    struct myType **bufs;
    struct myType *fixed_bufs[TEST_SZ];

    bufs = (struct myType **)malloc(TEST_SZ * sizeof(struct myType *));


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      fill_data(bufs);
      fill_data(fixed_bufs);

      printf("nth iter: %d => %d %d\n", i, bufs[TEST_SZ-1]->a, bufs[TEST_SZ-1]->b);
      printf("fixed_bufs nth iter: %d => %d %d\n", i, fixed_bufs[TEST_SZ-1]->a, fixed_bufs[TEST_SZ-1]->b);

      empty_data(bufs);
      empty_data(fixed_bufs);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've moved the code directly into your question. Please do not use external links, always include the relevant code in the post.

Comment: By the way, apart from the fact that you are casting the return value of `malloc`, [which you should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3889449), your code is correct and works fine. You might want to also `free()` your `bufs` variable in the end, but that's not a problem per se. The error must be somewhere else, show us more.

Comment: If you’re working on a platform that supports [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), use it. If you compile and link with debugging information, it will identify where you have problems with line numbers etc.  it is utterly invaluable.